# Create onTab listener class for map in Android

Tags: android, android-mapview

I am developing one Map project in Android. In this App, Some cluster icons are placed on the map. I want to set a listener for cluster icon click. So i decide to override a method onTap() in my custom overlay class (say ClusterMarker).  How could i set listener class for this?
Please provide me the right way to do this.......

like,
ClusterMarker (my custom Overlay class)

```
  @Override
    public boolean onTap(GeoPoint p, MapView mapView) {

        Projection pro = mapView.getProjection();
        Point ct = pro.toPixels(center_, null);
        Point pt = pro.toPixels(p, null);
//....
....
...
        return false;
    }
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found how to create listener class for onTap Event. But actually listener class not needed here. Because My custom Overlay in turn do that work. For that I have to add my custom overlay object to mapview.